# Starting dhcpd: [FAILED]

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, centos, dhcp

I have a Centos 6 virtual machine using KVM.

When I start the DHCPd service "service dhcpd start", I get the following:

```
Starting dhcpd:       [FAILED]
```

When I execute "dhcpd", I get the following:

```
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.1.1-P1
Copyright 2004-2010 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Not searching LDAP since ldap-server, ldap-port and ldap-base-dn were not specified in the config file
Wrote 0 leases to leases file.

No subnet declaration for eth1 (10.0.0.5).
** Ignoring requests on eth1.  If this is not what
   you want, please write a subnet declaration
   in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
   to which interface eth1 is attached. **


No subnet declaration for eth0 (192.168.121.176).
** Ignoring requests on eth0.  If this is not what
   you want, please write a subnet declaration
   in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
   to which interface eth0 is attached. **


Not configured to listen on any interfaces!

This version of ISC DHCP is based on the release available
on ftp.isc.org.  Features have been added and other changes
have been made to the base software release in order to make
it work better with this distribution.

Please report for this software via the CentOS Bugs Database:
    http://bugs.centos.org/

exiting.
```

Here's my dhcpd.conf:

[dhcpd.conf screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shUEA.png)

How can I fix this? I want to configure the DHCPd on eth1.

Can someone help me please and provide me with the exact details and commands?

Comment: This is impossible to debug without having your config. Please post the dhcpd configuration file.

Comment: Ok I just did. I attached an image to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you have a read of the [dhcp.conf man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/dhcpd.conf).

The reason dhcpd is not starting is explicitly stated in your question - you have not told it to listen on any interfaces.

To listen on eth1 as you've stated you need, at a minimum, something similar to the following clause in dhcpd.conf:

```
subnet 10.0.0.5 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
   range 10.0.0.6 10.0.0.254;
}
```

But you will need to adjust it to suit how your eth1 is configured - I made an assumption about the mask and required range.

The dhcpd.conf file that is pre-installed probably has a lot of presests that just need to be uncommented to get it working. It is probably quite well annotated as well.

Comment: I just added the following to the dhcpd.conf but nothing changed:

Comment: subnet 10.0.0.5 netmask 255.255.255.0 { range 10.0.0.11 10.0.0.254 }

Comment: Well, first you missed off the ; at the end of the range. As already asked, can you append your entire dhcpd.conf file in the question. Also, have you had a read of the man page as suggested? You are kind of expected to do some leg work yourself.

Comment: Ok I just did. I attached an image.

Comment: Did you remove all the other content or was it a blank file to start with?

Comment: It was blank from the beginning.

Comment: Nevermind I just changed 10.0.0.5 to 10.0.0.0 to represent the network and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Good! Feel free to up vote and accept the answer (with the tick).